# Header location

Tags: php, css, html

I am editing a plugin, and I need to make it so that this line `<h4><span><strong>100%</strong></span>` which ends up making a circle with a number in it, show up in the top right of the website instead of in its random spot, how can I make it so it is in a certain area? This is the line that needs to be moved, `<h4><span><strong>100%</strong></span>` Thanks, and sorry for the noobish question

Comment: There is nowhere near enough information to answer your question.

Comment: Once you add the id that @AramSahradyan suggested, I would suggest you remove the `span` and `strong` tags and replace any functionality they are achieving in your CSS file. Your HTML is very cluttered. Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 1):

HTML code:

```
<h4 id="yourId"><span><strong>100%</strong></span></h4>
```

CSS: code

```
#yourId { position: top: 10px; right: 10px; position: absolute; }
```

If you need it to stay always there even if you're scrolling then use this one

```
#yourId { position: top: 10px; right: 10px; position: fixed; }
```